# Dual monitor issue with Lenovo P50+Quadro M1000M

Tags: nvidia, gnome, gdm

I used to work with a dual screen setup (Lenovo P50 + external monitor). For an unknown reason, the external monitor stays black and seems not to be detected. When I use gdm3, only the builtin monitor is used, and when I switch to lightdm, only the external one is used, never both. I tried with several nvidia drivers (from 390 to 430), I also tried with the open-source one. I tried to purge then reinstall Nvidia drivers, manually install them, but the result is always the same, only one display at a time. I know that the GPU works as the two monitors are used when I dual boot on Windows.

Any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: Have you checked the screen settings in each case?

Comment: It used to work, but as soon as I tried to use NVidia drivers, it stopped working. Only one screen is detected. However I remove all NVidia drivers, remove the Nouveau one from blacklist and restore default driver and I recovered my two screens.

Answer (score 1):

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135103/ubuntu-19-04-screen-tearing-with-nvidia-gtx-1660-ti)
gdm3 disables external monitors when options nvidia-drm modeset=1 is set.  You can choose:

- modeset=1: No screen tearing, can't use external monitors
- modeset=0: Screen tearing, but can use External monitors

The fact it wouldn't work in lightdm still is a bit odd.  I recall reading somewhere there's an issue with external monitors where it will try to output via VGA even if the monitor is connected by other means.